# Python's `unittest` lacks an `assertHasAttr` method, what should I use instead?

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert, python-unittest, assertion

Of the many, many assert methods in [Python's standard `unittest` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), `.assertHasAttr()` is curiously absent. While writing some unit tests I've run into a case in which I'd like to test for the presence of an attribute in an object instance.

What's a safe/correct alternative for the missing `.assertHasAttr()` method?

Comment: Just use `assert hasattr(...)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Came up with an answer as I was writing the question. Given a class/test case that inherits from `unittest.TestCase`, you can just add a method based on `.assertTrue()`:

```
def assertHasAttr(self, obj, intendedAttr):
    testBool = hasattr(obj, intendedAttr)

    # python >=3.8 only, see below for older pythons
    self.assertTrue(testBool, msg=f'obj lacking an attribute. {obj=}, {intendedAttr=}')
```

Duh.

I didn't find anything on google when I was searching before, so I'll leave this here in case anyone else runs into a similar issue.

## update

I've updated my answer to use the neat new ["self-documenting" feature for f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging) that was added in python 3.8. If you want a `assertHasAttr` func that will be compatible with any python (including <=3.7), change the last line to instead be:

```py
# last line of original answer, will work with any python
self.assertTrue(testBool, msg='obj lacking an attribute. obj: %s, intendedAttr: %s' % (obj, intendedAttr))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can write your own:

```
HAS_ATTR_MESSAGE = '{} should have an attribute {}'

class BaseTestCase(TestCase):

    def assertHasAttr(self, obj, attrname, message=None):
        if not hasattr(obj, attrname):
            if message is not None:
                self.fail(message)
            else:
                self.fail(HAS_ATTR_MESSAGE.format(obj, attrname))
```

Then you can subclass `BaseTestCase` insteadof `TestCase` with tests. For example:

```
class TestDict(BaseTestCase):

    def test_dictionary_attributes(self):
        self.assertHasAttr({}, 'pop')  # will succeed
        self.assertHasAttr({}, 'blablablablabla')  # will fail
```

Comment: Nice. I was not aware of `TestCase.fail()`

Answer (score 4):

Going for the most succint answer so far:

```
self.assertTrue(hasattr(myInstance, "myAttribute"))
```

altough Dan's hint in a comment to the OP is also a valid answer:

```
assert hasattr(myInstance, "myAttribute"))
```

just not quite as syntactically aligned with the typical assertions from the unittest package.