# How can I mock dynamic attributes using django test case?

Tags: python, unit-testing, django-unittest

I have some functionality that makes a request to a third party. Within that request are some values that are dynamically created—for example, a date.

```
# example.py

...

payload = json.dumps({
    'id': uuid.uuid4(),
    'name': 'example',
    'date': datetime.now(),
    'foo': 'bar'
})

...

response = self.make_request(url, params=None, data=payload, method='post')
```

The functionality works great. Now I am attempting to write a unit test.

```
# test_example.py

@mock.patch('path.to.module.make_request')
test_successfully_does_stuff(self, make_request_mock):
    make_request_mock.return_value = {
        'status': 'OK'
        'success': True,
    }

    self.make_request()

    ...    

    make_request_mock.assert_called_with('https://example.com', params=None, data=json.dumps({
        'id': uuid.uuid4(),
        'name': 'example',
        'date': datetime.now(),
        'foo': 'bar'
    })
```

Asserting `called_once` works great:

```
make_request_mock.assert_called_once()
```

What I would like to assert, is that the `make_requet` call has all of the necessary attributes. Meaning I'd like to assert that `id`, `name`, `date` are included in the request. If I add a new attribute—or accidentally remove an attribute in the code, I'd like my test to pick that up.

When I run this test, I get an error that my expected and actual data doesn't match. This makes sense as `datetime.now()` and `uuid4()` will render different values when they are called.

For example, here is the result from date:

```
Expected: "date": "2023-07-05T20:00:28.130604"
Actual:   "date": "2023-07-05T20:40:51.575151",
```

I realize that the mock data is completely arbitrary and it could be anything I want. However I feel it may be important to test this. Is there a way to assert that my call has the necessary attributes?

**EDIT**

For clarification, it's the object attributes I want to assert are there, the actual values aren't as important.

Answer (score 0):

This is from a slightly older thread, but it seems [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078636/pythons-unittest-lacks-an-asserthasattr-method-what-should-i-use-instead) thread has potential solutions.

Since the values aren't of much concern, you could test that an attribute exists on the requesting instance:

```
self.assertTrue(hasattr(make_request_mock, 'date'))
```

If there are a large number of attributes, this approach may seem a bit much.